# Optimize PHP Code - Function Displaying and PHP Notice of Undefined Variable

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Any suggestions, below is function of toy variant - function loadProductVarients

At present its displaying :-

a) Toy Variant Name Only, wherein i intend to achieve product name and variant name. For example if Hotwheels is company, Ferrari is Product and Zsi is its Variant.

Now below function is displaying only Zsi as variant name, i intend to achieve Ferrari Zsi as variant name

I think the variable of product needs to be added in $temp1, but despite using many combinations - i am unable to achieve it.

b) Second is getting PHP Notice: Undefined variable: temp1 & temp2 Notice in function loadproductvarients

I am on learning PHP - your help and advise will be much appreciated !!

**Edit**

Hello Lodder,

Original Function

```
   function loadProductVarients($id,$minprice,$maxprice,$fuel_type){
        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
        $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
        global $Itemid; 
        $Vcond="";
        if($minprice!="" and $maxprice!=""){
        $Vcond.=" and (v_price between ".$minprice." and ".$maxprice.")";
        }elseif($minprice){ $Vcond.=" and v_price >= ".$minprice."";
        }elseif($maxprice){ $Vcond.=" and v_price <= ".$maxprice."";}

        if($fuel_type!="")
            $Vcond.=" and v_fuel_type='$fuel_type' ";

        $sql = "Select *  from #__newcar_variants  Where v_prod_id='".$id."' $Vcond and v_status='1'";

        $database->setQuery($sql);
        $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
    $list="";
        if($rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($row->v_small_img!=""){
                    $img = "uploads/variants/".$row->v_big_img ;
                }else{
                    $img="templates/pioneer_home/images/dvd1.jpg";
                }       

    $temp1.='<li><a href="index.php?newcar&id='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->v_id.'">'.$row->v_name.'</a></li>';
    $temp2.='<li>Rs. '.$row->v_price.'</li>';
            }
            $list.='<div class="sliding-box-middle"><ul>'.$temp1.'</ul></div>';
            $list.='<div class="sliding-box-right"><ul>'.$temp2.'</ul></div>';

        }else{
            $list.='<p>No Variants.</p>';
        }
        return $list;
    }


  $sql = "Select *  from #__newcar_variants  Where v_prod_id='".$id."' $Vcond and v_status='1'";
```

**Below is the modified code as advised written with changes :-**

```
       function loadProductVarients($id,$minprice,$maxprice,$fuel_type){
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $Vcond="";
        if($minprice!="" and $maxprice!=""){
        $Vcond.=" and (v_price between ".$minprice." and ".$maxprice.")";
        }elseif($minprice){ $Vcond.=" and v_price >= ".$minprice."";
        }elseif($maxprice){ $Vcond.=" and v_price <= ".$maxprice."";}

        if($fuel_type!="")
            $Vcond.=" and v_fuel_type='$fuel_type' ";

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__newcar_variants');      
        $query->where($db->quote($Vcond), $db->quote($id), $db->quote('v_status=1'));    

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        $list="";
        if($rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                if($row->v_small_img!=""){
                    $img = "uploads/variants/".$row->v_big_img ;
                }else{
                    $img="templates/pioneer_home/images/dvd1.jpg";
                }       

    $temp1.='<li><a href="index.php?newcar&id='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->v_id.'">'.$row->v_name.'</a></li>';
    $temp2.='<li>Rs. '.$row->v_price.'</li>';
            }
            $list.='<div class="sliding-box-middle"><ul>'.$temp1.'</ul></div>';
            $list.='<div class="sliding-box-right"><ul>'.$temp2.'</ul></div>';

        }else{
            $list.='<p>No Variants.</p>';
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Comment: Please use Joomla coding standards for your database queires: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Comment: Hello Lodder, as advised rewritten the code as per coding standards, however getting a new notice. May pl advise !! Thanks for the link for Joomla coding standards

Comment: Hi, change `$db->quote(v_status=='1')` to `$db->quote('v_status=1')`

Comment: Thanks, sorry to bother in again. The notices though have gone, but the variants are not getting displayed against the model. Earlier the variants were getting displayed. May suggest - if missing anything !!

Comment: try `var_dump($rows);` to see if there are actually any result being taken from the database. I think it's something to do with you `->where()` part of the query. `$Vcond.=" and v_fuel_type='$fuel_type' ";` so it's starting with `and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a concatenation on variables that are not set.

Replace

```
 $temp1.='<li><a href="index.php?new&id='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->v_id.'">'.$row->v_name.'</a></li>';
 $temp2.='<li>Rs. '.$row->v_price.'</li>';
```

By

```
$temp1='<li><a href="index.php?new&id='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->v_id.'">'.$row->v_name.'</a></li>';
$temp2='<li>Rs. '.$row->v_price.'</li>';
```

Or

```
$temp1 = '';
$temp2 = '';
// CODE
$temp1.='<li><a href="index.php?new&id='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->v_id.'">'.$row->v_name.'</a></li>';
$temp2.='<li>Rs. '.$row->v_price.'</li>';
```

I didn't get your first problem though.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Using above though removing error notice, but its only displaying only one of the product variants. I mean say Ferrari has 3 variants - zsi, lsi, msi. So using the code above only displaying one variant i.e zsi

Comment: Yes, as I said, I didn't get your first problem. Variants are in the v_name field, right ? Did you try to echo something in the foreach ($rows as $row) loop to see if you really got 3 variants ? Are you sure your query returns 3 rows ?

Comment: yes, variants are v_name. What I asked in my first query :- at present the fields in variants are displayed only with variant name i.e zxi,lxi,exi, hxi. While what i itend to achieve it is to display both product and variant name under variant name. I mean Ferrari zxi, ferrari lxi, ferrari exi and ferrari hxi. The original sql query is correctly displaying - but only variants. However, the product name i.e prod_id='$Carmodel' along with v_name variants is not getting displayed - despite trying many combination.